# Calculate Euclidean distances between all rows in matrices A and B

Tags: r, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have two matrices, `A` and `B`, with `N_a` and `N_b` rows, respectively. I need to calculate the Euclidean distance between all pairwise combinations of an element in `A` (`a`) and another in `B` (`b`), such that the output of the calculation is an N<sub>a</sub> by N<sub>b</sub> matrix, where cell `[a, b]` is the distance from a to b. I've started an example below.

```
# Example
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000, 5, 50), ncol = 5)
B <- matrix(rnorm(10000, 0, 50), ncol = 5)

# Return N_a x N_b matrix of euclidean distances, where [a,b] is the
# distance from a to b
```

Comment: you can use `outer()` or prepare the matrix of the results and then fill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one-liner without loops, without additional packages, and a little bit faster:

```
euklDist <- sqrt(apply(array(apply(B,1,function(x){(x-t(A))^2}),c(ncol(A),nrow(A),nrow(B))),2:3,sum))
```

Speed comparison:

```
> microbenchmark(jogo  = for (i in 1:nrow(A)) for (j in 1:nrow(B)) d[i,j] <- sqrt(sum((A[i,]-B[j,])^2)),
+                mra68 = sqrt(apply(array(app .... [TRUNCATED] 
Unit: seconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  jogo 3.601533 4.724619 5.403420 5.549199 6.098734 6.470888    10
 mra68 1.334661 1.635258 2.473297 2.542550 3.247981 3.348365    10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Example
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000, 5, 50), ncol = 5)
B <- matrix(rnorm(10000, 0, 50), ncol = 5)
d <- matrix(NA, nrow(A), nrow(B))
for (a in 1:nrow(A)) for (b in 1:nrow(B)) d[a,b] <- sqrt(sum((A[a,]-B[b,])^2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using one of my packages and parallelizing. Note that the current build on github is unstable, so you have to install from a prior commit from yesterday.

#### Edit: v0.7.1 is now stable, you don't need to use the commit-ref

This solution is only faster if both matrices are very large and/or you have a lot of cores. But it was fun for me to write, so:

```
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/imputation", 
  ref= "75723b769ed2ceae8c915d00089a31f059e447aa")
library(microbenchmark)
library(parallel)

f <- function(a, b) {
nnodes <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(nnodes)
d <- do.call("cbind", clusterApply(cl, x= parallel:::splitRows(a, nnodes),
         fun= function(x_sub, b) {
            apply(x_sub, 1, function(i, b) {imputation::dist_q.matrix(x= rbind(i, b), ref= 1L, q=2)}, b= b)
          }, b= b))
stopCluster(cl)
return(d)
}

a <- matrix(rnorm(50000), 1000)
b <- matrix(rnorm(50000), 1000)
d <- matrix(NA, 1000, 1000)
# run on 4 cores
microbenchmark(jogo= for (i in 1:nrow(a)) for (j in 1:nrow(b)) d[i,j] <- sqrt(sum((a[i,]-a[j,])^2)),
               alex= f(a,b), times= 10L)

Unit: seconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 jogo 4.190531 4.196546 4.289265 4.265351 4.358022 4.486445    10   b
 alex 3.585672 3.603485 3.783583 3.760859 3.966435 4.048676    10  a
```

You could probably improve on this using `library(Rdsm)` if you really wanted to... But I'll recommend using jogo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 interdist_func <- function(x, y){
    apply(y, 1, FUN=function(y_i){
      sqrt(colSums((t(x)-y_i)^2))
    })
 }
 

set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000, 5, 50), ncol = 5)
B <- matrix(rnorm(10000, 0, 50), ncol = 5)

d <- matrix(NA, nrow(A), nrow(B))

microbenchmark(
jogo  = 
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) for (j in 1:nrow(B)) d[i,j] <-sqrt(sum((A[i,]-B[j,])^2)),

mra68 = 
sqrt(apply(array(apply(B,1,function(x){(x-t(A))^2}),c(ncol(A),nrow(A),nrow(B))),2:3,sum)),

roboshea = 
apply(B, 1, FUN=function(B_i){sqrt(colSums((t(A)-B_i)^2))}))

#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#     jogo 486.0123 553.45700 585.69967 580.20000 619.26870  751.2992   100  b 
#    mra68 512.1435 606.38120 653.00116 639.32560 675.40945 1011.6164   100  c
# roboshea  29.5313  32.95525  42.32124  37.87175  41.27385  128.2292   100  a
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast method in base R is `sqrt(outer(rowSums(A^2),rowSums(B^2),"+")-2*tcrossprod(A,B))` (`tcrossprod(A,B)` is a slightly faster alternative to `A%*%t(B)`):

```
1.000 crossdist(A,B)
1.049 crossdist2(A,B)
1.442 sqrt(Rfast::Outer(Rfast::rowsums(B^2),Rfast::rowsums(A^2),"+")-2*Rfast::Tcrossprod(A,B))
1.996 proxy::dist(A,B)
2.035 Rfast::dista(A,B)
2.396 sqrt(outer(rowSums(A^2),rowSums(B^2),"+")-2*tcrossprod(A,B))
2.409 sqrt(outer(rowSums(A^2),rowSums(B^2),"+")-2*A%*%t(B))
2.945 as.matrix(pdist::pdist(A,B))
5.152 pracma::distmat(A,B)
8.550 apply(B,1,function(x)sqrt(colSums((t(A)-x)^2)))
173.815 sqrt(apply(array(apply(B,1,function(x){(x-t(A))^2}),c(ncol(A),nrow(A),nrow(B))),2:3,sum))
177.913 {d=matrix(,nrow(A),nrow(B))for(i in 1:nrow(A))for(j in 1:nrow(B))d[i,j]=sqrt(sum((A[i,]-B[j,])^2))}
```

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericMatrix crossdist(NumericMatrix x,NumericMatrix y){
  int n1=x.nrow(),n2=y.nrow(),ncol=x.ncol(),i,j,k;
  if(ncol!=y.ncol())throw std::runtime_error("Different column number");
  NumericMatrix out(n1,n2);
  for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
      double sum=0;
      for(k=0;k<ncol;k++)sum+=pow(x(i,k)-y(j,k),2);
      out(i,j)=sqrt(sum);
    }
  return out;
}')

Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericMatrix crossdist2(NumericMatrix x,NumericMatrix y){
  int n1=x.nrow(),n2=y.nrow(),ncol=x.ncol(),i,j,k;
  if(ncol!=y.ncol())throw std::runtime_error("Different column number");
  NumericMatrix out(n1,n2);
  double rs1[n1],rs2[n2],sum;
  for(i=0;i<n1;i++){sum=0;for(j=0;j<ncol;j++)sum+=pow(x(i,j),2);rs1[i]=sum;}
  for(i=0;i<n2;i++){sum=0;for(j=0;j<ncol;j++)sum+=pow(y(i,j),2);rs2[i]=sum;}
  for(i=0;i<n1;i++)for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
    sum=0;
    for(k=0;k<ncol;k++)sum+=x(i,k)*y(j,k);
    out(i,j)=sqrt(rs1[i]+rs2[j]-2*sum);
  }
  return out;
}')

set.seed(1)
A=matrix(rnorm(1000,5,50),ncol=5)
B=matrix(rnorm(10000,0,50),ncol=5)

b=microbenchmark(times=100,
  sqrt(apply(array(apply(B,1,function(x){(x-t(A))^2}),c(ncol(A),nrow(A),nrow(B))),2:3,sum)),
  {d=matrix(,nrow(A),nrow(B));for(i in 1:nrow(A))for(j in 1:nrow(B))d[i,j]=sqrt(sum((A[i,]-B[j,])^2))},
  apply(B,1,function(x)sqrt(colSums((t(A)-x)^2))),
  sqrt(outer(rowSums(A^2),rowSums(B^2),"+")-2*tcrossprod(A,B)),
  sqrt(outer(rowSums(A^2),rowSums(B^2),"+")-2*A%*%t(B)),
  crossdist(A,B),
  crossdist2(A,B),
  Rfast::dista(A,B),
  proxy::dist(A,B),
  pracma::distmat(A,B),
  as.matrix(pdist::pdist(A,B)),
  sqrt(Rfast::Outer(Rfast::rowsums(B^2),Rfast::rowsums(A^2),"+")-2*Rfast::Tcrossprod(A,B))
)

a=aggregate(b$time,list(b$expr),median)
a=a[order(a[,2]),]
writeLines(paste(sprintf("%.3f",a[,2]/min(a[,2])),gsub(" ","",a[,1])))
```