# Compute the Euclidean distances between corresponding rows of 2 matrices

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have 2 matrices A and B, and I want to compute the Euclidean distances between 1st row of A and 1st row of B, 2nd row of A and 2nd row of B, etc. I know I can use `rdist` function to compute the distances for all row combinations of A and B and get the needed values (diagonal values in the result), but I feel like there could be a more efficient way to compute only the needed values. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of the code you're using and the results it's giving right now, and what results you would rather see? Also, are you using `rdist` in the `rdist` package, or `rdist` in the `fields` package? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a nice way to do that. Let

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(4 * 8), nrow = 4, ncol = 8)
B <- matrix(rnorm(4 * 8), nrow = 4, ncol = 8)
```

Then

```
sqrt(rowSums((A - B)^2))
# [1] 3.295312 3.222073 6.857711 2.991980
```

where `A - B` does element-wise subtraction, we may square the resulting matrix element-wise, compute the row sums of this matrix using `rowSums` and take the square root element-wise.

Comment: Here is a version that allows `A` and `B` to have different number of rows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553686/calculate-euclidean-distances-between-all-rows-in-matrices-a-and-b